# Using zonal_stats with python in QGIS to calculate statistics for each image

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, zonal-statistics, rasterstats

I work with Python in QGIS,
I want to calculate statistics for each image that I have with a specify shapefile and save result after, 
I tried to do like this:

```
from rasterstats import zonal_stats        
layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values()
for layer in layers:
    stats = zonal_stats("/home/myshape.shp",layer)
```

but it gives me error TypeError: invalid path.

I tried to solve this problem but didn't find how.

Comment: Is `"/home/myshape.shp"` the full path to your polygon shapefile?

Comment: Yes I want to give short path to not have error with long path, but I think the problem is in the raster path 'layer'

Comment: many thanks for your help, now it works with layer.source()

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped! Will post the comment as an answer for the convenience of others =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `layer.source()` to get the paths of the rasters which is required by the `zonal_stats` module. Your code should look like:

```
from rasterstats import zonal_stats        
layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values()
for layer in layers:
    stats = zonal_stats("/home/myshape.shp", layer.source())
```